# Backbone.JS Events not firing on second render

Tags: backbone.js

Alright, so I'm pretty new to `Backbone.js` right now and I've encountered a problem that it seems many other people have had, but I can get the proposed solution to work.

Long story short I have a `ul` view that manages the `li`s inside of itself as sub-views whenever the `ul`s collection changes. The first render works fine and the `Soccer.Teams.Li` click event will fire. If a `add` or `change` event happens on the collection, the "rerendered" `li` subviews no longer have click events bound.

Here's the code in question:

```
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function () {
        console.log('closing time!');
        this.undelegateEvents();
        this.remove();
        this.unbind();
        if (this.onClose) {
            this.onClose();
        }
    };
Soccer.Teams.ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ul',
        className: 'ui-listview',
        lis: [],
        initialize: function(teams){
            this.teams = teams;
            this.teams.on('add change', this.render, this);
        },
        render: function(){
            while(this.lis.length>0){
                this.lis[0].close();
                this.lis.shift();
            }
            this.$el.empty();
            this.$el.attr('data-role','listview').css('margin','0px').css('width','220px').attr('id','teams-list');
            this.teams.forEach(function(team){
                this.lis.push(new Soccer.Teams.Li(team));
                this.$el.append(this.lis[this.lis.length-1].render().$el);
            }, this);
            $("#teams-list-container").html('').append(this.el);
            this.$el.listview();
            this.delegateEvents();
            return this;
        }
    });

Soccer.Teams.Li = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: compileTemplate('team-li'),
        tagName: 'li',
        initialize: function(team){
            this.team = team;
        },
        events: {
            'click a': 'open'
        },
        open: function(event){
            console.log('here');
            event.preventDefault();
            this.$el.parents('ul').find('.ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
            this.$el.addClass('ui-btn-active');
            var teamView = new Soccer.TeamView(this.team);
            teamView.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            this.$el.empty();
            this.$el.append(this.template(this.team));
            this.delegateEvents();
            return this;
        }
    });
```

As you can see I am `unbinding` and `undelegating` as well as `redelegating`. See any problems?

Comment: Calling `delegateEvents` in an event-less view doesn't do anything productive and if you need to manually call `delegateEvents` you're probably doing something wrong. And you will want `this.lis = [ ];` inside `initialize` rather than `lis: []` in the prototype. The `$('#teams-list-container')` should be handled by the `ListView` caller, not the view itself and you don't want to call that more than once. Also consider what [`.html('')`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) does to events. Just a few possibilities as it is too late for a proper answer.

Comment: Hmmm...don't know what fixed it, but removed all ``delegateEvents``, changed the ``lis`` declaration, and moved the ``teams-list-container`` part and it all worked. Also replaced ``.html('')`` with ``.empty()``. Thanks!

Comment: Also, it seems that now I can remove the ``lis`` ``.close()`` portion entirely and it still works. However, does removing that create a memory leak? Or will the ``.empty`` on the ListView take care of everything for me? Thanks again for your help @muistooshort